# How can I define a Typescript object return value for a function?

Tags: typescript

My function looks like this:

```
parseRange = (text) => {
    var arr = [];
    var lower = null;
    var upper = null;
    if (!text || text === "") {
        lower = null;
        upper = null;
    }
    else if (text.indexOf("-") > 0) {
        arr = text.split("-");
        lower = +arr[0];
        upper = +arr[1];
    }
    else {
        lower = +text;
        upper = null;
    }
    return {
        lower: lower,
        upper: upper
    };
};
```

I am familiar with returning strings and numbers but how can I specify the return is an object with a lower and upper parameter?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

```
parseRange = (text: string) : { lower: number; upper: number; } => {
    // ...
    return {
        lower: lower,
        upper: upper
    };
};
```

or

```
parseRange = <(text: string) : { lower: number; upper: number; }> ((text) => {
    // ...
    return {
        lower: lower,
        upper: upper
    };
});
```

or

```
var parseRange : (text: string) => { lower: number; upper: number; } = (text) => {
    // ...
    return {
        lower: lower,
        upper: upper
    };
};
```

or

```
parseRange = function (text: string) : { lower: number; upper: number; } {
    // ...
    return {
        lower: lower,
        upper: upper
    };
};
```

or

```
function parseRange(text: string) : { lower: number; upper: number; } {
    // ...
    return {
        lower: lower,
        upper: upper
    };
};
```

or

```
interface RangeResult {
    lower: number;
    upper: number;
}
function parseRange(text: string) : RangeResult {
    // ...
    return {
        lower: lower,
        upper: upper
    };
};
```

Comment: That covers pretty much every method of specifying this return type! Very comprehensive.

Answer (score 8):

TypeScript [infers function return types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html), so this results in a compile error without having to specify the types explicitly:

```
var parseRange = (text) => {
    return {
        lower: 5,
        upper: 6
    };
};

var range = parseRange("");
range.foo; // compile error
```

[Live example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=var%20parseRange%20%3D%20(text)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lower%3A%205%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20upper%3A%206%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20range%20%3D%20parseRange(%22%22)%3B%0D%0Arange.foo%3B%20%2F%2F%20compile%20error) which shows the error:

> The property 'foo' does not exist on value of type '{ lower: number; upper: number; }'.