# typescript return destructuring?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
function print(): (number, string) {
    return {1,'my'}
}
```

Above code shows error, I expect I can use `const {num, my} = print()`. What's the right way to specify return type?

Comment: `: {num: number, my: string }` and `return { num: 1, my: 'my' }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I define a Typescript object return value for a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719834/how-can-i-define-a-typescript-object-return-value-for-a-function)

Comment: [Tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) might be more intuitive for you.

Comment: @apokryfos why?

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković what if I've 10 object? I need a set of 10 object key? That looks so repeatative.

Comment: @apokryfos That link appears to be deprecated, replaced by https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types

Comment: @FayChen Read the documentation on Tuples provided, it's exactly what you want to do, and addresses "won't that be repetitive" since you don't have to add key names.

Comment: If you're destructuring things you will have to repeat keys/elements anyway. If you have 10 things just use an array and don't destructure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types). It looks like this:

```
function print(): [number, string] {
    return [1,'my']
}

const [num, my] = print();
```

See demo in [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=27&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE4zFAFASgFyIDaYIAtgEYCmqANIgM5TpgDmAuogN4BQifiqSlBCokhAIw0A5KQCeUttwC%203bhASMiJUnTkcAvCmbYcAbm5A)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return an object which has a string and a number. Now, this object should contain property names - so, let's define the return type and use it in your function

```
type myReturnType = {
  n: number,
  s: string
}

function print():myReturnType {
   return {n:1,s: 'my'}
}

let {n, s} = print();
```

Here is the shorthand version of the above code:

```
function print():{n: number, s: string}{
    return {n:1,s: 'my'}
}

let {n, s} = print();
```